# Get list of items with name or null based on another table values

Tags: mysql, sql, jpql

I have schema like this:

[image]

Now I would like to write query which returns me list of items with borrower name only if book is borrowed now, otherwise borrower name should be null. 
I feel like it should be easy; I have been trying with just multple joins and NULL conditions but I still can't get what I want. Maybe should I change my schema?

Comment: How do you know if the book is borrowed now?  Is the `return_date` NULL?  Some sample data would be a great help.

Comment: Yes return_date is NULL when book is borrowed now. Is it ok or should i add status or smth?

Comment: If this isn't some sort of exercise, then I would simply make it two queries. Is it an exercise?

Comment: @Jonas Tonny No, but i want to get those values in one query, store as java objects and display on view (JSP)

Comment: @JonasTonny I would love to see some proof to back up that claim.  There is nothing wrong with doing a single query with two joins.

Comment: @Siyual I agree with you, there's nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT items.*, borrowers.first_name, borrowers.last_name
FROM items
LEFT JOIN borrows ON borrows.item_id = items.id AND return_date IS NULL
LEFT JOIN borrowers ON borrowers.id = borrows.borrower_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

`select Items.title,
  case 
    when b1.return_date is null then b2.first_name || ' ' || b2.last_name 
    else null 
  end as 'Borrower name' 
from Items i
join Borrows b1 on b1.item_id = i.id
join Borrowers b2 on b2.id = b1.borrower_id`

This always selects the title of the item, and concats the first_name and last_name of the borrower, but only if return_date is null. Otherwise, null is selected as 'Borrower name'

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` onto the `Borrowers` table on the condition that the `return_date` `IS NULL`.

This should work for you:

```
Select      I.*,
            B.First_Name,
            B.Last_Name
From        Borrows     W
Join        Items       I   On  W.item_id = I.Id
Left Join   Borrowers   B   On  W.borrower_id = B.id
                            And W.return_date Is Null
```